# 7-segment display driver IC

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, display, 7segmentdisplay

Which IC can I use to control 7-segment display? I want to make simple projects like a reaction timer but I don't have an Arduino or some other microcontroller available. **What ICs can I use instead?**

Comment: There are thousands of ICs that can drive (or control) a 7 segment display but this is too many to list.

Comment: suggestion:7447.

Comment: There's also the CD4511, that can be used to drive common-cathode displays. The 74LS'47 and 74LS'247 are used to control common-anode displays. That's an important distinction by the way: you need to know whether you have a CA or CC display. If you didn't order them yet, you need to pair them with the right driver.

Comment: Here's a [few links](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=7-segment+display&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl) that may help you learn how to use 7-segment displays.

Comment: This article seems to be a good one to start with: [The 7-segment Display](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/7-segment-display-tutorial.html). It talks about common-cathode and common-anode configuration and how to drive the display with CD4511.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about LED 7 segment displays (as opposed to LCDs), you could use the '47 or '247 devices from the 7400 logic family, e.g. [7447](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls47.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @fmunkert

If you're talking about 7-segment LCD, you could use [CD4054/4055/4056](http://www.yd-tech.com.tw/pdf/CMOS/4054.pdf) CMOS chips.